# Where to Set Condition with Where Clause in CTE With Rownumber

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am a little confused as to where would be the preferred place to add the condition when using `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTITION`.

I have a table containing the following columns:

`UserID, BranchNumber, MemberDate` and `MemberStatus`

**Note: A member can have multiple memberships at different locations:**

*The following code gives me one less record: 17069*

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
 *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY [MemberDate] DESC) AS RowNumber 

FROM MemberTable 

WHERE BranchNumber = '01'
) 
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RowNumber = 1 AND MemberStatus = 'Active'
```

*The following code gives one additional record: 17070*

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
 *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY [MemberDate] DESC) AS RowNumber 

FROM MemberTable 

WHERE BranchNumber = '01' AND MemberStatus = 'Active'
) 
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

I am just confused as to why the difference and which is the right way?

**The correct amount of records is 19000.**

Comment: There's no preferred place to add the condition. There is only one *right* place. It depends on what you need. I'm unclear on what you need. Do you want the first item that is active, or do you want items that are first and active?

Comment: I want all Most recent records that are `Active` and at `Branch 01`.

Comment: I would say use `WHERE` inside the CTE filter out the unneeded rows sooner then later.

Answer (score 1):

Both are "right" in a sense they return what is asked. (2) gives more records because you apply extra condition (`MemberStatus = 'Active'`) in the subquery(cte). So record where MemberStatus are not equal to "Active" cannot have "RowNumber=1" . (1) doesn't filter such rows in CTE, so it's possible that it returns record[s] with `RowNumber=1 and MemberStatus <> 'Active'` which got removed from final resultset by applying condition in outer query.

Answer (score 1):

The `ROW_NUMBER` is evaluated after the `WHERE`. Let's make it more intuitive by splitting the two apart:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
SELECT 
 *

FROM MemberTable 

WHERE BranchNumber = '01' AND MemberStatus = 'Active'
) 
, CTE2 AS (
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY [MemberDate] DESC) AS RowNumber 
  FROM CTE1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

I think it is pretty clear now that you need the filter applied first. Think of the CTE's as virtual tables. You can debug this by changing the final select to `SELECT * FROM CTE1`. Just look at what is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The queries are different, so I would expect the records to be different.

The first query says:

- Get All records where `BranchNumber = 1`, order by the `MemberDate` and partition on `userId`
- Then, from that result set, get me the **1st** record for each user, only if `MemberStatus is Active`

The second query says:

- Get me all `activemember` records from `BranchNumber = 1`, order by the `MemberDate` and `partition on userId`
- Then, from the result above, get me the **first** instance.

So, the first result set may be getting the latest record from the user, inactive or not, and then you filter out the inactive ones.  The second will only return active records, so I would expect more.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned **"A member can have multiple memberships at different locations"** , try partition it by the `"BranchNumber"` as well and see if it gives you the result you are looking for.

The way you are doing it, it is returning the Very last Membership start date for any location, if you partition by the BranchNumber it will return the very last Membership start date for each user for each Branch Number , try something like this

```
;WITH  
CTE 
AS
  (
   SELECT *
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, BranchNumber ORDER BY [MemberDate] DESC)  
                                                                   AS RowNumber 
    FROM MemberTable 

  ) 
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RowNumber = 1 AND MemberStatus = 'Active'
```